# How to Create oracle PL/SQL function to store/retrieve data from table

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

i am beginner so i am confusing about what should i write in return type.

and how to write function to select all records from  particular ID

```
2   shadik  27  25-05-14    4000    pakistan
1   AKSHAY  28  30-04-20    2000    INDIA
3   GAURANG 25  06-05-20    4000    USA
4   NIRAV   23  16-11-14    1000    CANADA
5   VEER    29  26-12-19    5000    DUBAI
```

Comment: If you are a beginner, I suggest you study the [PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/) which is part of Oracle documentation.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statements for your sample data; a complete description of the problem; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the error messages generated by **YOUR** solution; and the expected output. You state you want to return all the records for a particular ID but you have not given any column headers so we do not know what is an ID value. You have not given the table definition or expected output so we do not know if you are expecting a single row or multiple rows of output.

Comment: Do you want to RETURN 1 row or several rows at once? Based on your requirements the solution can differ. I suggest you edit your question as mentioned above THEN people would be amenable to helping you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple option is to return refcursor; you don't have to *declare* any type for that.

Here's an example based on Scott's sample schema. Function returns all rows from the `EMP` table whose `DEPTNO` column matches value passed as function's `IN` parameter.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_deptno in number)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open rc for select * from emp
  7                where deptno = par_deptno;
  8    return rc;
  9  end;
 10  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test(10) from dual;

F_TEST(10)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.81       2450                    10
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.81       5000                    10
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.82       1300                    10


SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this is a bit more custom you can return rows from a function using a type.

```
create or replace type myRecordType
 as object
 ( x int,
 y date,
 z varchar2(25)
 )
 

create or replace type myTableType
 as table of myRecordType;
/

create or replace function my_function return myTableType
 as
 some_data myTableType := myTabletype();
 begin
 for i in 1 .. 10 loop
 some_data.extend;
 some_data(i) :=
 myRecordType( i, sysdate+i, 'record ' || i );
 end loop;
 return some_data;
 end;
 /

select * from TABLE ( cast( my_function() as mytableType ) )
 /

X    Y    Z
1    09-FEB-22    record 1
2    10-FEB-22    record 2
3    11-FEB-22    record 3
4    12-FEB-22    record 4
5    13-FEB-22    record 5
6    14-FEB-22    record 6
7    15-FEB-22    record 7
8    16-FEB-22    record 8
9    17-FEB-22    record 9
10    18-FEB-22    record 10
```